# Trouble with scopes and blocks in javascript. Declaring variables

Tags: node.js, function, variables, asynchronous, global

When I declare a variable inside of one of my functions I am not able to call on it outside of that function.

```
    async function submitCardInfo () {
    try {
       const example1 = 'testing';
       let example2 = 'testing2';
    } catch (error) {
        setRunningError('Error Submitting Card Credentials')
        console.log(error)
    }


console.log(example1);
```

this is my function to submit Card info and I declare a couple of variables at the bottom. When I call on those variables later in my code(outside of the function submitCardInfo) they aren't defined. That console.log example will say that example1 is undefined.

EDIT BELOW

```
async function submitCardInfo () {
    try {
       data  = {
     example1:'testing',
     example2:'testing2',

    } catch (error) {
        setRunningError('Error Submitting Card Credentials')
        console.log(error)
    } await submitCardInfo()


console.log(example1);
```

Ok when I run a similar code to this I still get undefined. Can you please try and example using this example and explain how you would do it.

SOLUTION Below -
Hello what I do now is use class and this.(variable) and I am able to change the value of the variable and use it anywhere in my code. Another way is to declare a variable using var outside of the local scope and then you are able to use that variable other places in your code.

Comment: Re-read your lessons on variable scope.

Answer (score 2):

Variables in Javascript are only accessible within the function that they are declared in.  And, each time you call the function, it creates a new and different variable in that function.  This is referred to as "function scoping".  If you declare the variable with `const` or `let` (instead of `var`), then the variable is only available within the block that it is declared in. This is referred as "block scoping".

There is a "global scope" where variables can be accessible anywhere, but this is nearly always discouraged for a variety of reasons.  And, calling a function that changes a global value as its function is referred to as "side effect" programming and is also discouraged.

If you want to call the function and communicate the value of that variable back to the outside world (outside the function), then you can return it from the function where the caller can use the return value.

If you want to return more than one value, then you can put them in an object or an array and return the object or the array as the single return value.

If the function is `async`, then all `async` functions return a promise and the returned value inside the `async` function becomes the resolved value of the promise that is returned.  The caller would use `await` or `.then()` to get the resolved value of the promise.

In your specific function example, you should not that `async` functions would generally only be used if you had asynchronous operations inside the function and thus were interested in using `await` inside the function.  If you have no asynchronous operations, then it is simpler to code the function as a regular function (without the `async` keyword) and then you can just directly return a value and the caller can directly receive the return value.

Comment: @Prada - Review what?  The answer is still the same.  Also, the code you added to your question contains errors and will not even run.

Comment: From the code I sent how would I fix it so that it works and I am able to call the variable anywhere in my code.

Comment: I just put global.(varname) and I am able to call it anywhere. Is there any problem with doing that.

Comment: @Prada - Yes, there are lots of problems with using globals and it is not something you should do.  It is not a good way to program.  The details of "why" are a whole different subject and there are thousands of articles on that topic already.

Comment: @prada - The code you've posted doesn't make enough sense to me so I can't understand its purpose and what you have won't even run (it has mismatched brackets that make it thoroughly confusing).  If you want to edit your question to describe in words what the code is supposed to accomplish, then we could perhaps suggest a better way to write it.

Comment: Yea sorry I wrote a very bad example since my actual code is 600 lines so I just tried to break it down.

Comment: Ok so in my code I have a async function named startTask. Inside of startTask I have many more async functions in there doing seperate tasks. so one of those functions are named submitCardInfo. What this function will do is grab an Id and then store it inside of a variable that I will use later in another function. The problem I have is I am not able to call on it later and I return the variable inside of the function and when I call on submitCardInfo I use .then and I return a resolve and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I used the same exact method for another function and it works but for some reason this one wont. If you need any more information let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Thats happening because variables have diferrence scopes. Function and global scope, `let` and `const` also have another scope which is block scope, that means that if you declared it inside curly braces {} (Ej: your try, catch block, a function, etc.) they will only live there. Thats why you can't access them from ouside of any other part of your code. The only way you can access a variable from any part of your file is that if you declare it in the global scope

Comment: Yes, sorry I kind of asked the question wrong. I already know that all I just don't know how to make it a global variable when I declare it inside of a function.